# Найти число в строке по суффиксу

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть рандомная строка "item-strtock **bxc_id_47913**" data-id="117848907_47913" id=117848907_47913_store_quantity><icon

Как можно получить число, зная суффикс ?
Суффикс bxc_id_ , необходимо получить число 47913

Comment: `bxc_id_` не суффикс, в крайнем случае, это префикс (то, что предшествует).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем функцию preg_match, которая ищет по регулярному выражению '/bxc_id_(\d+)/' - в скобках указывается то, что нам нужно захватить. Все данные, которые найдет эта функция будут помещены в массив $matches, где первым элементом будет идти строка с префиксом, а вторым уже наш нужный номер (то, что соответствует "\d+", что означает одна или более цифр). [О регулярных выражениях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

```
<?php
$string = "item-strtock bxc_id_47913" data-id="117848907_47913";
$num = preg_match('/bxc_id_(\d+)/', $string, $matches) === 1 ? $matches[1] : null;
echo $num;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]